# Javascript trigger jsaction from chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to trigger a button (apparently working with the google JSAction framework) from the chrome console.

[image]

Seems that the part I should trigger is the `click:cOuCgd`

But I don't know how to trigger this kind of button.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share your code with us?

Comment: @goediaz it's not my code it's from the google hangout page, I want to programmatically click on the call button.

Comment: I just don't know what to write to trigger this button

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try mousedown & mouseup events as follows:

```
// Simulate mouse down
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));
// Simulate mouse release
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mouseup", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }))
```

I used this approach to simulate clicking Duplicate menu item in Google Calendar and it worked for me (see https://github.com/fabiosangregorio/google-calendar-quick-duplicate/issues/1).

Here is a sample UserScript where I use this approach: https://gist.github.com/balta2ar/407b1cbcb669545c926bb4aa9d4aaeb6

Comment: I am also trying to write a userscript to fix a Google site; in my case, I'm trying to automate Google Classroom.  I have, apparently, hit a dead end. Trying your simulateClick, I get the response, "Failed to construct 'MouseEvent': member view is not of type Window."  Did you ever come across this?

Comment: @DanOverlander nope, sorry, that message doesn't sound familiar to me

Comment: @DanOverlander I am literally trying to do the same thing...basically delete all the assignments (around 300+)...I just now want to be able to trigger the **Delete** button right now, so that delete pop up opens. Rest all is sorted already. Please let me know if we could help each other in any way.

Comment: Well, here's my script if you're interested: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/427800-google-classroom-helper  I *am* able to successfully inject a button onto the review-student's-assignment page, that when clicked automatically sets their score to 100, presses Return, and presses OK on the popup that shows up.  It's hardcoded to "Overlander" in the code - FYI. Otherwise, I do also use AutoHotKey to do some automation for the Review All page.

Comment: How can I receive 'element' ?

Answer (score 0):

For others that might want to do similar things:

I didn't manage to trigget the jsaction attribute. But:

Review posts have a hidden span, right after the span that is shown as the user review/comment.
So if you want to access the "Full Review" of an app in Google Play Store, just access it directly. 
I did it this way:

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].textContent;
console.log(x)
```

where i was the index of the HTMLCollection that is put out if you run

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")
```

Hope it helps it helps some non-programmers in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by attribute and then call click() on it like: `document.querySelector('[jsaction="click:cOuCgd"]').click()`